# Dynamic View for Car

Tags: views

I have made a view that contains only car manufacturer logos.

What I want is that when a user clicks on a logo they will be taken to a page that will display all cars for this manufacturer (in a view), depending on a link or something.

How to make this or to assign some arguments and where?

Answer (score 1):

**The Views Module and Contextual Filters**

I believe the Views module can accomplish all of your requirements.

Contextual filters will allow you to feed arguments into View using URL components.  You can customize your URL's using Views re-writing features.

---

**Video Tutorials:**

Check out Johan Falk's video series called "[Taming The Beast: learning Views With NodOne](http://nodeone.se/sv/node/20)"

Video 17 will show you how to rewrite field output so you can build the proper links.

Videos 19-24 should cover most of what you need regarding Contextual Filters.

Comment: thanks guys for your replies 
Citricguy, those stuff seem to be useful, I will take a look and back to work and you

Comment: I think Citricguy's is the best answer. In the view with the logo you rewrite the url adding the nid of the manufacturer, then you create a display with nid as contextual filter. You take the nid from the url giving the position of it and it's done!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the link to the view with arguments using the [Field Redirection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_redirection) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> A Drupal 7 field formatter for [Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/link), [Node Reference & User Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/references), Term Reference (as of v2.4) and [EntityReference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) (as of v2.4) fields that will perform a HTTP redirect to the given URL, node, user, term or entity object page. A field settings widget is provided to allow selection of the appropriate [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection).
>
> The recommended usage is to create a custom display setting for the "Full content", pick one of the redirect status codes above, e.g. 301, and hide all other fields to reduce processing & load time.